# Unable to read any question or answer in Android app due to black box

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, android-app

This is a bit of a more unusual bug to report:

[image]

The screenshot above is unedited - the black box is rendered by the Stack Exchange application.

**Phone:** [Samsung Galaxy Discover](http://www.samsung.com/ca/consumer/mobile/mobile-phones/smartphones/SGH-S730HKMBMC) running Android 4.0.4 (ICS)

Comment: I sometimes see this blacked out element when I'm scrolling though answers (galaxy s4)

Comment: It is censored due to a takedown request by the Bacon Lover Organization :P

Comment: What version of the app is this happening in?

Comment: @balpha: This is happening for me in v0.1.36.

Comment: @NathanOsman has this been an issue recently.  We have made a lot of changes around rendering.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas: As of v0.1.49, I still see this issue. ([Here's what this question looks like.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FMbd9.png))

Comment: @GeoffDalgas Same issue on my HTC Sensation XL running Android 4.0.3. Stack Exchange app v. 0.1.77. Once in a while it shows a question/answer correctly, but most of the time it does not.

Comment: I cannot confirm this bug in 1.0.3.

Comment: This happens to me as well on HTC Desire C, app version 1.0.3 -- I can't see a single question or answer on any SE site.

Comment: I have thus same problem using v1.0.3 on a Motorola Razr XT 910 Android version 4.0.4 It renders the app completely useless unfortunately

Comment: I've got this bug on an Acer Iconia A200, running 1.0.3 of SE app, Android version 4.0.3. Seems to work fine on a Droid 4, running 1.0.3, Android version 4.1.2

Comment: Still present in 1.0.5 of the app.

Comment: my sprint lg mach that has this problem 100% of the time is running android 4.0.4 as well. there seems to be a pattern to the  android versions affected.

Comment: Just to give folks an update, I'm still looking into this. I haven't been able to see it on a 4.0.3 or 4.0.4 emulator so we're looking into setting up a device lab to test this out from.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi: Which library are you using to render content? If you are converting markdown to html I suggets using http://uncodin.github.io/bypass/ which is much faster as it converts markdown directly to spanned string.

Comment: @Giorgi None, we're using WebViews directly. We can't use bypass because we need to do client-side prettifying of code blocks (and soon LaTeX)

Comment: I am also having this issue. I am using a HTC EVO 3D, Android 4.0.3, Stackexchange App 1.0.5.

Comment: Same here as well, Galaxy S2 running Android 4.0.4.

Answer (score 10):

**Update: 1.0.6 is now out.**

Good news everyone!

This has been fixed as of version 1.0.6 which should be hitting the Play Store within the next 6-8 hours.

Technical description follows for those inclined to read it.

Some backstory first: During our alpha we noticed that scrolling quickly through answers led to a flickering black box each time the contents of the answer were displayed. In our testing we learned that this was only happening on GPU accelerated devices. When we looked into it, it ended up being a bug with how the GPU acceleration handles `WebView`s which have a completely transparent background so we simply set the background on those views to be 1% opaque if the phone had hardware acceleration.

Well, it turns out that in 4.0.x there is a bug when you try to use transparent `WebView`s. I learned this by attempting to take a screenshot of the application running on a Samsung Galaxy Discover and seeing that the contents of the question (which was a big black box on my phone) was actually transparent on the screenshot.

As of version 1.0.6 we don't do our black-flickering hack on devices that are running below version 4.1 of the OS.

Comment: Awesome, hope it's the end of the Black Box saga. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think that's the fastest time between answer to bounty awarding that I've ever seen.

Comment: Lol, just a stroke of luck as you posted while I was browsing... all credit goes to the marvellous real time notification system! :D

Comment: this update fixes the issue for me. good work.

Comment: Black box appears again in StackExchange 1.0.40 in Android 4.0.3 Galaxy Note N-5100. But after a crash, the black box disappear. I wish someone can explain this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using v. 0.1.55 on a Pantech Element.

I see all question and answer text as a black box.  Quotes have a white background, so look like I'd expect text to look.  Links show as bright underlined blue on a black background.  Comments and Title are normal.

Comment: I have thus same problem using v1.0.3 on a Motorola Razr XT 910 Android version 4.0.4 It renders the app completely useless unfortunately