# Android app crashing while logging in on Android 4.0.4

Tags: bug, android-app

The StackExchange Android app crashes repeatedly while I enter my user name in the log in screen.

From the logs, I see

```
Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S2 running stock 4.0.4

Comment: Man, Android 4.0.4. Causing [all sorts of issues with the app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196968/unable-to-read-rendered-markdown-due-to-black-box).

Comment: Yes, unfortunately.