# Scrolling causes black flashes in the Android App

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When scrolling through a question, or its answers, or when first swiping between the two the post background often flashes solid black before the text is rendered.

This has been happening for a while now (couple of weeks maybe) but has just annoyed me enough to report it now.:-)

I'm hoping something can be done and it's not just because my phone (galaxy s2) is a potato, showing its age. Maybe it's as easy as setting the Web view's background to the default for posts (I'm not an android dev)?

Comment: I noticed this too, only recently though, in the [SO Moderator Election post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221594/222390). The sections in simple blockquotes don't flash black but the text in between them does. I'm on version 1.0.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I caused this when I noticed the return of [the black box issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196968/unable-to-read-any-question-or-answer-in-android-app-due-to-black-box) while remote testing on some low end devices, meaning I moved my "if they're on 4.0.x, don't fix the flickering since it's not happening" change to "if they're on anything lower than KitKat". Thinking about, I was a bit overzealous since I hadn't heard anyone on 4.1 or 4.2 reporting the black box issue so this might have been an issue with the remote testing service we were using.

As of the next version update (1.0.17) this will be fixed again.